# Deleting S3 objects with arbitrary tag-value

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, s3-lifecycle-policy, s3-object-tagging

I naively tagged S3 objects with a common key, but arbitrary values (a `UUID` per batch), believing it would be "easy enough" to go back and delete every object with the specified tag.

So far, my testing suggests that if I specify a lifecycle rule which filters based on key-only (no value), then it matches only objects which also have the key **and no value**, rather than matching all objects with that key **regardless of value**.

I'm currently waiting for midnight UTC just to make sure that the issue isn't between Terraform and Amazon S3. But if there's a known way to specify `apply rule to all objects with tag-key K`, that would be super helpful; the documentation I've found to date isn't quite that clear.

Bit of terraform for completeness:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_s3_bucket" {
  ...
  lifecycle_rule {
    id = "Tagged current version expiration"
    prefix = "my_prefix/"

    tags = {
      recyclable = ""
    }

    enabled = var.tagged_current_version_expiration_enabled

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      days = var.tagged_noncurrent_version_expiration_days
    }
    
    expiration {
      days = var.tagged_current_version_expiration_days
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid [the lifecycle rules documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-filter) is pretty clear on this point, and you'll have to write a rule for every UUID you created.

> The Lifecycle rule applies to objects that have both of the tags
> specified. Amazon S3 performs a logical AND. Note the following:
>
> Each tag must match both key and value exactly.
>
> The rule applies to a subset of objects that has all the tags
> specified in the rule. If an object has additional tags specified, the
> rule will still apply.

*must match both key and value exactly* seem to indicate that you can't use no wildcard here.

Comment: I would generally agree, except that specifying a "value" for a key is optional, both when tagging an object and when specifying a lifecycle rule.  If the only thing matched by a non-valued rule is a non-valued object-tag, then why support it at all? It's equivalent to "empty string is a unique value" and instead S3 could just have required a value with no loss of generality. Not saying you're incorrect, just that it's non-obvious how to interpret the idea of an optional tag-value.

Comment: I'd like to see lifecycle rules and S3 batch jobs support wildcard tag matching. IMO that would greatly enhance the functionality of S3 tags.